# Get the n'th element relative to it's parent with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to style the n'th element relative to it's parent, not relative to the document.
Got this:

css:

```
ul li:nth-child(2n){ background: #fff; }
```

html:

```
<ul>
<li></li> // background is white
<li></li>
<li></li> // background is white
</ul>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li> // background is white
<li></li>
</ul>
```

In this case, every seccond element get's a white background, start counting from the document, doesn't matter that the elements got a parent element "ul".

Now I want that at each "ul" element the count ist resettet. The result should look like this:

```
<ul>
<li></li> // background is white
<li></li>
<li></li> // background is white
</ul>
<ul>
<li></li> // background is white
<li></li>
<li></li> // background is white
</ul>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: [Your original code doesn't have that issue](http://codepen.io/zzzzBov/pen/xlDat).

Comment: Did you check the code before posting it here?

Answer (score 3):

```
ul > li:nth-child(2n) {background: #fff;}
```

This shouldn't be necessary, though. Your original code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5MKtK

Answer (score 0):

use this  [nth-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)
and the direct descendant selector

```
ul >li:nth-of-type(2n){ background: #fff; }
```

tool : http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

Comment: This is redundant considering `li` is the only element which can be validly contained within `ul`.